# Barplot on Rstudio

Tags: r, bar-chart

Can I make a barplot on Rstudio without uploading a dataset and just write the values of the variables on the script?

I found the command `barplot(table())`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Simply try with a vector. Example: `barplot(height = c(a=10,b=5,d=15))`

Comment: I think you may be looking for `with`, as in `with(mtcars, barplot(table(cyl)))`, or just do as @Ric suggested